# Django does not translate variables loaded on init

Tags: django

When I define a constant in Django file that is loaded while the app is initiating, it does not translate the value when I change the language.

Example:

widgets.py

```py
# widgets.py
from django.forms import widgets
from django.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

DEFAULT_TEXT = _('some text')

class MyWidget(widgets.TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        value = DEFAULT_TEXT
        ... other rendering things ...
        return super(widgets.TextInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from .widgets import MyWidget

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='name', widget=MyWidget)
```

When I try to use `DEFAULT_TEXT` its value is translated to the default init language but not evaluated to the current language on demand.

How could I fix this?

Comment: This probably has to do with the timing when this file is imported somewhere, rather than app initialization. I recommend you read about how python imports work.

Comment: If you need more help than that, we will need a more complete example that shows how you use this constant.

Comment: The constant is used as a label during widget rendering. The only place where it is imported is in a `fields.py` file to call a widget:
`field_name = models.CharField(...., widget=MyCustomWidget)`
and that widget uses `MY_CONSTANT`  in `render` function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with some more code so you can format it properly.